# How to match lines starting and ending with a digit and consisting of 1 to 6 characters?

Tags: grep, regex

I have this following file:

```
$ cat numbers
a1
12
12345
123456
19816282
1@$%6
```

I am using `grep "^[0-9]\{1,6\}$" numbers` which is giving me the following results:

```
12
12345
```

I am also expecting `1@$%6` in the results.

Comment: Try this "^[0-9].*{1,6}$"

Comment: it didn't work out. I want to display all lines which have a minimum of  1 digit and a maximum of 6 digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is actually

```
12
12345
123456
```

Your regex means "*A line consisting of 1 to 6 digits and nothing else*" so `1@$%6` doesn't match.

Comment: +1, is this because I am using `$` in my regex?

Comment: Yes, without the `$` it would mean "Any line that starts with 1 to 6 digits" which includes `1@$%6`.

Answer (score 3):

```
> grep "[0-9]\{1,6\}" numbers.txt
1
12
12345
123456
19816282
1@$%6
```

Comment: +1, but $ only specified that matched pattern should end with a number. please correct if I am wrong?

Comment: the ^"[0-9]\{1,6\}"$ will find pattern of 1 to 6 numbers between beginning and the end of a line. "[0-9]\{1,6\}"$ will find 1 to 6 number before end of a line.

Comment: This answer does not provide the intended matching logic that is described by the OP.  Also, there is no explanation in the answer.